# R statistics, panel data and NAs: replacing NA value in vector with a specific row in another vector using panel data

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, na, panel-data

My apologies for a poorly formulated question. I am new to R and to programming and for posting questions.

I am working with panel data. I have two context varying variables: cat (category that ranges from 1 to 4, where an individual have gambled in 3 out of 4 possible places) and d.stake = amount of money staked in a given category. Cat and d.stake are nested within the individual (id) (context independent variable).

I wish to make a difference score between the different categories amount staked in different categories.

I have created four variables. Two of them lag is a lag variable (ldstake and ldstake2) and two variables with difference scores (diff1 = stake - ldstake; diff2 stake - ldstake2), using the code

```
df.3$ldstake <- c(NA, df.3$d.stake[-nrow(df.3)])
df.3$ldstake[which(!duplicated(df.3$id))] <- NA


df.3$ldstake2 <- c(NA, df.3$ldstake[-nrow(df.3)])
df.3$ldstake2[which(!duplicated(df.3$id))] <- NA


df.3 <- df.3 %>%
 mutate(diff1 = d.stake - ldstake,
     diff2 = d.stake - ldstake2)
```

This give me the following dataframe:

```
id cat d.stake ldstake ldstake2 diff1 diff2
1   1    50      NA       NA     NA     NA
1   2    60      50       NA     10     NA
1   3    55      60       50     -5     5
2   1    34      NA       NA     NA     NA
2   2    74      34       NA     40     NA
2   4    12      74       34     -62    22
```

However, I wish to replace the first row of diff1 (the NA) for each individual with the third row of diff2 from each individual (See example below).

```
id cat d.stake ldstake ldstake2 diff1 diff2
1   1    50      NA       NA     !5!    NA
1   2    60      50       NA     10     NA
1   3    55      60       50     -5     !5!
2   1    34      NA       NA    *22*    NA
2   2    74      34       NA     40     NA
2   4    12      74       34    -62    *22*
```

Is this possible? I would be grateful to receive a script where I can replace the first NA value with the value of diff2 and last value for the individual (third or last observation). Furthermore, if there is a script that would do this automatically (that is create the difference score between cat2-1 cat3-2 and cat3-1) I would be grateful to receive any help.

All the best, 
Tony

Comment: it sounds like you ultimately are interested in differences between combinations of `d.stake` for a given `id` - is that right? Could you clarify what your final/desired data frame would look like in that case, given the different `cat` numbers? Did you want column names like `diff2-3` to reflect difference between second and third `cat` (independent of `cat` number), or is would it be the difference between `cat` 2 and `cat` 3?

Comment: That is right. The intention is to analyze gambling behavior in different contexts. However, as the individual has gambled in 3 locations I need to to consider that observations are nested within the individual. I want a column call diff1 (in a long format). However, considering your suggestion I would also like to have a categorical column explicitly stating  which cat categories that are compared (cat2vscat1; cat3vs1; cat4vs1; cat3vs2; cat4vs2; cat4vs3). Is that possible? and thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possibility based on something else I had been working on this past week.

```
library(tidyverse)

df_wide <- df %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = id, names_from = cat, values_from = d.stake) %>%
  as.data.frame(.)

data.frame(id = df_wide$id, combn(df_wide[-1], 2, function(x) x[,1]-x[,2])) %>%
  setNames(c("id", apply(combn(names(df_wide[-1]), 2), 2, paste0, collapse = "-"))) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -id, names_to = "cats", values_to = "diff") %>%
  drop_na()
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
     id cats   diff
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1     1 1-2     -10
2     1 1-3      -5
3     1 2-3       5
4     2 1-2     -40
5     2 1-4      22
6     2 2-4      62
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
  cat = c(1,2,3,1,2,4),
  d.stake = c(50,60,55,34,74,12)
)
```

Comment: Lovely! It appears that you have solved the issue! Thanks Ben and cheers :)